# Is it possible to assign a generic like Generic<Base> generic = new Generic<SubClass>();

Tags: c#, generics, mapping

I want to be able to declare a generic instance that takes a base class as a type parameter and then later assign it to a generic that takes the subclass as the parameter. I have been able to do similar things in Java, but I'm stuck here in C#.

The best use case for a problem like this would be to map different interactions to two class types, which I have done in this code snippet. I tried to declare a Base class and classes A and B that derive from it. Then I want to map a function which takes the two classes as parameters.

```
class Program
{

    public class Base {}
    public class A : Base {}
    public class B : Base {}

    public class TypePair
    {
        private Type left;
        private Type right;

        public TypePair(Type left, Type right)
        {
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }
    }

    public static Dictionary<TypePair, Func<Base, Base, bool>> typeMap = new Dictionary<TypePair, Func<Base, Base, bool>>();

    public static bool doStuffWithAandB(A a, B b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Did stuff with a and b!");
        return true;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var typePair = new TypePair(typeof(A), typeof(B));
        typeMap.Add(typePair, doStuffWithAandB); // <- Compiler error :(
        typeMap[typePair](new A(), new B());
    }
}
```

The compiler expects a generic (Func) like doStuffWithAandB(Base a, Base b) and not doStuffWithAandB(A a, B b). If C# does not allow such a functionality. Why is that and are the better solutions to problems like these?

Comment: The title is a bit misleading, because your problem is that you want to assign a `Func<A, B, bool>` (the `doStuffWithAandB`) to a `Func<Base, Base, bool>`. It's not about classes but delegates.

Comment: If it were possible, `typeMap[typePair]` would be a `Func<Base, Base, bool>`, so you could call it with *any* `Base` object as parameter and the parameter types may not match the requirements of `doStuffWithAandB`.

Comment: The problem here is that the arguments of a delegate (or method or function) are contra-variant, not co-variant.  That means you could assign a `Func<Base, Base, bool>` to a `Func<A, B, bool>` because you now that sending in `A` and `B` will work for something that takes `Base`, but not the other way round.  Note: the return type is co-variant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only interfaces and delegates can be specified as variant in C#. So if you define an `IGeneric<T>` interface, you can assing it to a `Generic<SubClass>`:

```
interface IGeneric<out T> { }

class Generic<T> : IGeneric<T> { }

class Base { }

class SubClass : Base { }

IGeneric<Base> obj = new Generic<SubClass>();
```

In C# 8.0+, interfaces may contain default implementations: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/default-implementations-in-interfaces/

You can't assing a `Func<Base, Base, bool>` to a `Func<Derived, SubClass , bool>` because the in parameter types `T1` and `T2` are contravariant:

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T1, in T2, out TResult>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
```

Please refer to @Eric Lippert's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48178244/7252182) for more information about this.

Comment: Thatm does not really answer the question.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: Maybe not but what is the actual question then? The title reads *Is it possible to assign a generic like `Generic<Base> generic = new Generic<SubClass>()`* and the answer to this is no, unless `Generic` is an interface.

Comment: Sure, but from the content we know that it´s actually about **delegates**, as Dirk pointed out in the comments.

Comment: And delegates support variance, so the answer should be yes.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine this would work as you think. Some API has a delegate that expects an instance of `Base`. Surely this API will call that delegate at some point with an arbitrary instance of `Base`, e.g. a `B`:

```
void DoSomething(Func<Base, bool> func)
{
    Base b = new B();
    func(b);
}
```

So by assigning a `Func<A, bool>` to a parameter of type `Func<Base, bool>`, that code would now provide a `B` for what you expect to be an `A`:

```
bool DoStuffWithA(A a)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a.SpecialAStuff);
}
```

The above would crash hardly at runtime, as `B` is not convertible to `A`.

On the other hand you can assign a `Func<Base, bool>` to a `Func<A, bool>`:

```
DoSomething(Func<A, bool> func)
{
    Base a = new A();
    func(a);
}
```

which you may call like this:

```
DoSomething(DoStuffWithBase);

bool DoStuffWithBase(Base b)
{
    Console.WriteLine(b.BaseStuff);
}
```

This works because the instance being passed to the delegate is type `A`, which inherits `Base`.

That´s what we call [**Contra-variance**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/).

Just an asside: while the **parameters** are contra-variant for a delegate, its **return-value** is co-variant, which means you can return anything that is **more** specific from your delegate, as every `Specific` already is a `Generic`.