# Contravariance invalid when using interface's delegate as a parameter type

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, contravariance, default-interface-member

Consider the contravariant interface definition with a delegate:

```cs
public interface IInterface<in TInput>
{
    delegate int Foo(int x);
    
    void Bar(TInput input);
    
    void Baz(TInput input, Foo foo);
}
```

The definition of `Baz` fails with an error:

> CS1961
> Invalid variance: The type parameter '`TInput`' must be covariantly valid on '`IInterface<TInput>.Baz(TInput, IInterface<TInput>.Foo)`'. '`TInput`' is contravariant.

My question is *why*? On first glance this should be valid, as the `Foo` delegate has nothing to do with `TInput`. I don't know if it's the compiler being overly conservative or if I'm missing something.

Note that normally you wouldn't declare a delegate inside an interface, in particular this doesn't compile on versions older than C# 8, since a delegate in an interface needs default interface implementations.

Is there a way to break the type system if this definition was allowed, or is the compiler conservative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR; This is correct according to the ECMA-335 spec, confusingly there are *some* situations when it does work

Assume we have two variables

```
IInterface<Animal> i1 = anInterfaceAnimalValue;
IInterface<Cat>    i2 = anInterfaceCatValue;
```

We can make these calls

```
i1.Baz(anAnimal, j => 5);
//this is the same as doing
i1.Baz(anAnimal, new IInterface<Animal>.Foo(j => 5));

i1.Baz(aCat, j => 5);
//this is the same as doing
i1.Baz(aCat, new IInterface<Animal>.Foo(j => 5));


i2.Baz(aCat, j => 5);
//this is the same as doing
i2.Baz(aCat, new IInterface<Cat>.Foo(j => 5));
```

If we now assign `i1 = i2;` then what happens?

```
i1.Baz(anAnimal, j => 5);
//this is the same as doing
i1.Baz(anAnimal, new IInterface<Animal>.Foo(j => 5));
```

**But `IInterface<Cat>.Baz` (the actual object type) does not accept `IInterface<Animal>.Foo`, it only accepts `IInterface<Cat>.Foo`.** The fact that these two delegates are the same signature does not take away from them being different types.

---

### Let's go into it a bit deeper

**Let me preface this with two points:**

**Firstly**, remember that co-variant generic types in interfaces can appear in *output* positions (this allows a more derived type), and contra-variant in *input* positions (allows a more base type).

> [**Covariance and contravariance in generics**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)
>
> In general, a covariant type parameter can be used as the return type of a delegate, and contravariant type parameters can be used as parameter types. For an interface, covariant type parameters can be used as the return types of the interface's methods, and contravariant type parameters can be used as the parameter types of the interface's methods.

With type parameters of the arguments you pass in, it's somewhat confusing: if `T` is covariant (*output*), a function can use `void (Action<T>)` which looks like it's an *input*, and can accept a delegate which is *more* derived. It can also return `Func<T>`.

If `T` is contra-variant the opposite is true.

**See [this excellent post by the great Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48178244/14868997) and [on the same question by Peter Duniho](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48177835/14868997) for further explanation on this point.**

**Secondly**, [ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_6th_edition_june_2012.pdf), which defines the spec of the CLI, says the following (my bold):

> **II.9.1 Generic type definitions**
>
> The generic parameter is in scope in the declarations of:
>
> - *snip...*
> - all members (instance and static fields, methods, constructors, properties and events) except nested classes.  **[Note: C# allows generic parameters from an enclosing class to be used in a nested class, but  adds any required extra generic parameters to the nested class definition in metadata. end note]**

So nested types, of which the `Foo` delegate is an example, actually don't have the generic `T` type in scope. The C# compiler adds them in.

---

Now, see the following code, I have noted which lines do not compile:

```cs
public delegate void FooIn<in T>(T input);
public delegate T FooOut<out T>();

public interface IInterfaceIn<in T>
{
    void BarIn(FooIn<T> input);     //must be covariant
    FooIn<T> BazIn();
    void BarOut(FooOut<T> input);
    FooOut<T> BazOut();             //must be covariant

    public delegate void FooNest();
    public delegate void FooNestIn(T input);
    public delegate T FooNestOut();
    
    void BarNest(FooNest input);        //must be covariant
    void BarNestIn(FooNestIn input);    //must be covariant
    void BarNestOut(FooNestOut input);  //must be covariant
    FooNest BazNest();
    FooNestIn BazNestIn();
    FooNestOut BazNestOut();
}

public interface IInterfaceOut<out T>
{
    void BarIn(FooIn<T> input);
    FooIn<T> BazIn();               //must be contravariant
    void BarOut(FooOut<T> input);   //must be contravariant
    FooOut<T> BazOut();
    
    public delegate void FooNest();
    public delegate void FooNestIn(T input);
    public delegate T FooNestOut();
    
    void BarNest(FooNest input);        //must be contravariant
    void BarNestIn(FooNestIn input);    //must be contravariant
    void BarNestOut(FooNestOut input);  //must be contravariant
    FooNest BazNest();
    FooNestIn BazNestIn();
    FooNestOut BazNestOut();
}
```

Let's stick to `IInterfaceIn` for the moment.

Take the invalid `BarIn`. It uses `FooIn`, whose type parameter is covariant.

Now, if we have `anAnimalInterfaceValue` then we can call `BarIn()` with a `FooIn<Animal>` argument. This means that the delegate takes an `Animal` argument. If we then cast it to `IInterface<Cat>` then we could call it with a `FooIn<Cat>`, which **demands** a parameter of type `Cat`, and the underlying object is not expecting such a strict delegate, it expects to be able to pass *any* `Animal`.

So `BarIn` can therefore only use a type which is the same or *less* derived than what is declared, therefore it cannot receive the `T` of `IInterfaceIn` which may end being *more* derived.

`BarOut` however, is valid because it uses `FooOut`, which has a **contra**-variant `T`.

Now let's look at `FooNestIn` and `FooNestOut`. These actually re-declare the `T` parameter of the enclosing type. `FooNestOut` is invalid because it uses the co-variant `in T` in an output position. `FooNestIn` *is* valid though.

Let's move on to `BarNest`, `BarNestIn` and `BarNestOut`. These are *all* invalid, because they use delegates which have a **co**-variant generic parameter. **The key here is that we do not care if the delegate actually uses the type parameter in a necessary position, what we care about is whether the variance of the generic parameter of the delegate matches the type that we are supplying.**

**Aha, you say, but then why do the `IInterfaceOut` nested parameters not work?**

Let's look at ECMA-335 again, where it talks about generic parameters being valid, and asserts that each part of the generic type must be valid (my bold, `S` refers to a generic type e.g. `List<T>`, `T` means a type parameter, `var` means the `in/out` of the respective paramtere):

> **II.9.7 Validity of member signatures**
>
> Given the annotated generic parameters `S = <var_1 T_1, ..., var_n T_n>`, we define what it means for various components of the type definition to be valid with respect to `S`. We define a negation operation on annotations, written `¬S`, to mean “flip negatives to positives, and positives to negatives”
>
> **Methods.** A method signature `tmeth(t_1,...,t_n)` is valid with respect to `S` if
>
> - its result type signature `t` is valid with respect to `S`; and
> - **each argument type signature `t_i` is valid with respect to `¬S`.**
> - each method generic parameter constraint type `t_j` is valid with respect to `¬S`. **[Note: In other words, the result behaves covariantly and the arguments behave contravariantly...**

So we flip the **variance** of the type used in the method arguments.

The upshot of all this is that it is *never* valid to use a nested co- *or* contra-variant type in a method argument position, because the required **variance** is flipped, and therefore will not match. Whichever way round we do it, it won't work.

Conversely, using the delegate in the return position always works.

Comment: You can ignore that. Without the actual declarations, I thought they were interface types, not delegates. Also, I'm not awake enough to say this with authority, but I _think_ that the distinction you make about delegate types, is really a distinction that exists for _any_ generic type with a variant parameter when it itself is being used in a type-variant scenario. I.e. the thing that reverses the co/contra aspect is the extra level of indirection via the parameter or return value, not that it's a delegate or interface per se. (Intuitively this makes sense to me, since delegates are really ...

Comment: ... just single-member interfaces with simpler syntax.) (sigh...just over _again_)

Comment: Found a link to Eric L, *EDIT* ooh you wrote something also. You're right I think. Except about them being single member.... :-)

Comment: Yeah, pretty much anything Lippert writes on the topic is going to be the gold standard. He always knows this stuff, but more importantly, 99.94% of the time he has a unique clarity in the way he expresses the facts that make it so much easier to understand than if anyone else wrote it. (Not sure what you object about my characterization of delegates...that I compared them to interfaces at all, or that they are equivalent to an interface with _more_ than one member? Please note that I don't intend to mean they are the same to the runtime...just that semantically they're equivalent.)

Comment: Them being more than one member. See ECMA-335 II.14.6.3, and a decompiler obviously also. Admittedly, ECMA doesn't *require* async methods, but MS's CLI implementation does do so.

Comment: _"Them being more than one member"_ -- ah, you just misunderstand me. As I noted above, I'm not talking about the mechanical (implementation details) aspects of a delegate, only the semantics. You can only "implement" a single "interface" member with a delegate type. It has more flexibility than an interface of course, because _any_ code anywhere can "implement" the member. But it can only represent a single "interface" member.

Comment: Yeah, I knew already that's what you meant, just me being pedantic. I wonder what @EricLippert has to say about this, any way we can ping him?

Comment: Sure...his blog site has contact info.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words Peter; I know this stuff reasonably well mostly because I wrote the specification and implemented it in the compiler. :)  As for what I have to say about this answer: it looks very complete and well-argued but I have not got the time today to go through it point by point to make a detailed critique.  If you have a specific question I'm happy to consider it but I likely will not get to it until tomorrow. Busy day, chipping the pieces of a compiler out of the compiler mines.

Comment: @EricLippert Yeah I'd appreciate your thoughts. I can't quite put my finger on what's wrong with that last bit re `IInterfaceOut`, but something doesn't feel quite right. Why does `IInterfaceOut.BarIn` work but `IInterfaceOut.BarNest` and `BarNestIn` do not? I don't think even I fully understand why it does that. Happy for you to edit my post directly if you want. I also originally put more emphasis on the nested re-declaration, which I've since realized is actually mostly irrelevant.

Comment: @Charlieface: I left Microsoft well before the delegates-in-interfaces feature was added but I might be able to remember enough about the design proposals we discussed back then to figure it out. Not today though!

Comment: @EricLippert Have you had a chance to look this over yet?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is co- versus contravariance problem.

1. The `Foo` delegate is **not** a member of the interface. It is a nested type declaration.
2. `IInterface<A>.Foo` and `IInterface<B>.Foo` are two different types.
3. This makes the `foo` parameter of two different `IInterface<T>.Baz` methods (with `T` = `A` and `B`) incompatible.
4. Therefore you cannot substitute a `IInterface<A>` for a `IInterface<B>` or vice-versa (no matter what the inheritance relationship between `A` and `B` is.
5. Conclusion: `IInterface<T>` cannot be variant (neither co- nor contra-).

Resolution:

- Move the delegate to the top level (in the body of a namespace). It is a type declaration, so, it does not need to be embedded.
- Or embed it in a type with no type parameter. E.g., you could create a non-generic `IInterface` for this (and keep your generic one).

But @EricLippert certainly knows better.

Comment: I hope the @EricLippert in my text will phone home :-)

Comment: Given your conclusion, it seems this *is* a variance problem, so I think you should remove your first sentence.

Comment: @Servy okay, I modified my sentence slightly.

Comment: If it is not a variance issue (meaning that `IInterface<Cat>.Foo` is never assignment-compatible to `IInterface<Animal>.Foo` then how do you explain the `FooNest BazNest()` example that I gave, which *does* compile? By the way, not sure what your downvote was, did I say something wrong?

Comment: @Charlieface: I didn't downvote (I actually upvoted yesterday). You may be right. My feeling was the nested types wouldn't participate in the variance of the surrounding type.