# Why can't I take a contravariant interface as a parameter to a method on the interface?

Tags: c#, contravariance

I'm trying to setup a CoR with interfaces where a handler in the chain can be a for a less derived event type using contravariance. I create this interface to do it.

```
public interface IHandler<in TEvent>
{
    void SetNext(IHandler<TEvent> next);
    void Handle(TEvent event);
}
```

It fails with the compiler error

> CS1961 Invalid variance: The type parameter 'TEvent' must be covariantly valid on 'IHandler.SetNext(IHandler)'. 'TEvent' is contravariant.

I thought this should be valid since `IHandler` is covariant in `TEvent`. What am I missing?

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177452/covariance-and-contravariance-with-func-in-generics/48177835#48177835 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66401278/contravariance-invalid-when-using-interfaces-delegate-as-a-parameter-type/66402759#66402759

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes a lot of sense if you think in terms of `Animal`s and `Dog`s.

Let's make up some concrete implementations first:

```
class AnimalHandler: IHandler<Animal> { 
    public void SetNext(IHandler<Animal> next) {
        // animal handlers can handle cats :)
        next.Handle(new Cat());
    }

    // ...
}

class DogHandler: IHandler<Dog> { ... }
```

Since the type parameter of `IHandler` is contravariant, a `IHandler<Animal>` is a kind of `IHandler<Dog>`:

```
IHandler<Animal> someAnimalHandler = new AnimalHandler();
IHandler<Dog> dogHandler = someAnimalHandler;
```

Suppose that your `SetNext` method is allowed to be declared in `IHandler`, then I can call `SetNext` with another `IHandler<Dog>` on this `dogHandler`, since that is exactly the type that `dogHandler.SetNext` accepts.

```
IHandler<Dog> anotherDogHandler = new DogHandler();
dogHandler.SetNext(anotherDogHandler);
```

But that shouldn't be possible! After all, `dogHandler` actually stores an instance of `AnimalHandler`, whose `SetNext` method accepts `IHandler<Animal>`, and a `IHandler<Dog>` is not necessarily a `IHandler<Animal>`, is it? Imagine what would happen if the implementation of `AnimalHandler.SetNext` actually runs - keep in mind that the `next` parameter is a `DogHandler` - we would be asking a dog handler to handle a cat!

Therefore, it is invalid to declare `SetNext` with a contravariant `TEvent`.

This is specified more precisely [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/interfaces#variance-safety). It is said that the type `IHandler<TEvent>` is *input-unsafe*, and so is prohibited as a parameter.

`TEvent` would have to be invariant for both of your interface methods to compile.

Comment: Another way of putting it is that each level of indirection causes the variance to flip, so `void SetNext(IHandler<IHandler<TEvent>>)` *would* be valid, see fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/stEU4Q

Comment: I don't understand where the problem actually comes in. In your example, if I call `dogHandler.SetNext(anotherDogHandler)`, any calls `dogHandler` makes on `anotherDogHandler` would be through the `IHandler<Dog>` interface - meaning they would be required to pass an instance of `Dog` to the methods. Since `dogHandler` is a `IHandler<Dog>` shouldn't it always be interacting with `Dog` objects?

Comment: @just.another.programmer The problem is that the _implementation_ of `dogHandler.SetNext` only takes `IHandler<Animal>`, and `anotherDogHandler` is not a kind of `IHandler<Animal>`. Maybe I shouldn't have omitted the implementation with "...". I have edited to make it more concrete, so you can see exactly what bad things would happen if this were to be allowed.