# Method returning Action<T> from covariance

Tags: c#, delegates, covariance

It has the following `interface`:

```cs
public interface ICovariant<out T>
{
    public void InputFunc(Func<T> func);
}
```

I get the following compile-time error:

> Invalid variance: covariant type parameter 'T' is used in contravariant position. Parameter must be input-safe

The location of `Func<T>` is **input**. `Func<T>` is `Func<out T>`, so it is **output**.

OK, I was wrong. Get information that location is relevant.

However, when I add the following method, an error occurs.

```cs
public interface ICovariant<out T>
{
    public void InputFunc(Func<T> func);
    public Action<T> ReturnAction();
}
```

> Invalid variance: covariant type parameter 'T' is used in contravariant position. Method return type must be output-safe

The location of `Action<T>` is the **output**. `Action<T>` is `Action<in T>`, so it is **input**.

what? Unlike before, this time the location doesn't matter.

Why do the two examples perceive each other differently?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sweeper's accepted answer is good; I want to provide a slightly different way to think about why your proposed program is illegal.  Before I do that, once again allow me to apologize for the low quality of the error messages here. I couldn't come up with anything better and apparently they have not been improved much in the subsequent ~15 years.

```
public interface ICovariant<out T>
{
    public Action<T> ReturnAction(); // Why is this illegal?
}
```

Why is this illegal? Try to implement it and then see what goes wrong!

```
class Animal {...}
class Mammal : Animal {...}
// ... and so on ...
class Danger: ICovariant<Mammal>
{
  public Action<Mammal> ReturnAction()
  {
    return (Mammal m) => { m.ProduceMilk(); };
  }
}
```

`Danger` meets the requirements of `ICovariant<Mammal>` -- it returns an action, that action takes a Mammal, and it does a thing -- makes the mammal produce milk:

```
ICovariant<Mammal> danger = new Danger();
Action<Mammal> action = danger.ReturnAction();
action(new Goat()); // Goat milk, mmmmm
```

But `ICovariant<Mammal>` is convertible to `ICovariant<Animal>` because its covariant, so we could also write:

```
ICovariant<Animal> danger = new Danger();
// ICov<Animal> produces an Action<Animal>
Action<Animal> action = danger.ReturnAction();
action(new Chicken());
```

And now we have milked a chicken. Nothing good will come of the attempt.

The lines above are perfectly legal; they cannot be an error. To prevent this situation from happening, the compiler has to make the interface itself illegal.

Answer (score 3):

> Unlike before, this time the location doesn't matter.

The location *does* matter! This compiles perfectly:

```
public interface ICovariant<out T>
{
    public void AcceptAction(Action<T> action);
}
```

What the contravariant type parameter in `Action` does, is that it makes its corresponding type argument have the *opposite* position of where you have put it - if it is originally in an input position, it is now in an output position, and if it is originally in an output position, it is now in an input position.

"Contra-" means "opposite", so that's an easy to remember this behaviour :D Though this particular behaviour is probably not where the name "contravariance" comes from. [Eric Lippert's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2202349/5133585) explains why it's called that.

So this compiles too (the position of `T` gets "flipped" twice, and so it is back to the output position):

```
public Action<Action<T>> ReturnsNestedAction();
```

If you just think about how you would actually *call* `ReturnAction`, you should be able to intuitively convince yourself that, indeed, `T` in `ReturnAction` *is* in an input position:

```
Action<T> action = someICovariant.ReturnAction();
action(someT); // I am *inputting* an instance of T here!
```

Likewise, you can do the same for `AcceptAction` and see that `T` is indeed in an output position there:

```
someICovariant.AcceptAction(t => {
    Console.WriteLine(t);
});
/*
Imagine the implementation of AcceptAction invoking its parameter at some point.
That is analogous to AcceptAction *returning* some instance of T and we print it out
The difference being that instead of "return someT;", 
AcceptAction would do "action(someT);", but the fact it is producing an instance of T
doesn't change
*/
```

If you are interested in how this is specified in technical terms, you can go read [this section of the language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/interfaces#17232-variance-safety).

See also this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70641265/5133585) about similar "flipping positions" behaviours when declaring a contravariant type parameter.